# How to fake a connection refused in rust?

Tags: networking, tcp, rust

I want to program something, that's quite similar to a firewall, a firewall that only lets the request through if it's the second try from the same IP.

But in order to do that, i have to inspect the package header, without opening the tcp connection/stream and returning a ACK. The rust std library doesn't have any way, as far as i know, to do that.

So how could i refuse a connection depending on the IP in rust?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is too bizarre a thing to want to do for a standard library to provide functions for it. I expect you'd have to use a low level system-specific API to achieve this, so you should specify what OS you want to do that for.

Comment: This is only supposed to be working on linux @mcarton. I have already tried around a bit with `smoltcp`, but when i start listening on the port, it crashes (`thread 'main' panicked at 'source slice length (9) does not match destination slice length (4)', /rustc/e1884a8e3c3e813aada8254edfa120e85bf5ffca/library/core/src/slice/mod.rs:2745:13
note: run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display a backtrace`), and i'm not even sure if i *could* achieve this with smoltcp